# Django model not visible

Tags: python, django

I create project **blog**, and application **books**.

The next, i write to file models.py (example in djangobook)

and change setting file (setting.py)

in block INSTALLED_APPS i add:

```
'blog.books',
```

but, if i write to console:

```
python manage.py validate
```

**No module named blog.books**

why?

Comment: You will have to share the file structure with us; and perhaps you need to read through the [modules and packages chapter of the Python tutorial](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/modules.html) to understand how imports and packages work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your project is named "blog" and your app is "books" than in settings.py you should have only stated app name:

'books',

Django will know to look in current project only.

Project name should be skipped!

As for the error message. Django will look for blog.blog.books (will add project name at the from automatically), will not find it, and will complain about it. Its just because you and django both add "blog." and end up with something that both of you do not want.